# Vscode cannot connect to remote Linux （_WebSocket close with status code 1006）

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh

Remote connection to Linux. After entering the password, there are two prompts on the right

[image: 11]

And the terminal cannot input
The remote directory could not be loaded

I had tried countless times in many ways
Reinstall vocode，delete `~/.vscode-server/` directory, and so on.
What the hell should I do.

[image: 22]

Comment: Check if you can connect to the remote server via a normal ssh session.

Comment: The remote server can be connected  normally via any ssh session

Comment: Hey did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 19):

1. Find out which instance of WSL is running

```
wsl -l --running
```

2. Terminate all running instances of WSL

```
wsl --shutdown
```

3. Then simply restart WSL

```
wsl
```

Comment: I must add this solution works but if you must close all VSCode windows that were connected to WSL (they will start retrying to connect when we shutdown wsl). This is important because you will get the same error over and over and you might have forgotten that you have a VSCode window open on another desktop.

Answer (score 8):

This can be resolved by rebooting the host machine (i.e. reboot your Windows PC) and restarting your WSL-2 box, then launching VSCode remote again.

No idea why this happens but from time to time I experience this issue.

Confirmed issue on:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
Vs code 1.60.1
```

Comment: I used `wsl --shutdown` & then restarted my wsl 2 box which worked without restarting PC. vscode 1.63.1 thanks :)

Comment: can confirm @dgBP solution worked for me. running `wsl --shutdown` from command prompt and then re running wsl fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This worked for me and when I went back into the Ubuntu shell and ran `code .` it updated the VS Code Server. VS Code 1.66.1.

Comment: Yay the Windows experience! Some things will never change.

Comment: After trying the other solutions, a Windows reboot was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else comes across this question it's very easy.

1. You're most likely using a reverse proxy
2. Just enable websocket support on your reverse proxy.

Ex.
If you are using Docker and the popular NGINX Proxy Manager; when you are adding a proxy host make sure to choose `websocket support`

No more 1006 error :)

Answer (score 3):

Just clean up the `/root/.vscode-server` directory, vs code will create a new one when you connect again to the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I had to delete `/home/<user>/.vscode-server`, but it worked perfectly and I didn't have to restart my computer. I just had to force VS Code to reload. The next time I'll test deleting only `/home/<user>/.vscode-server/data` though, to try to keep the saved extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the setting `remote.WSL.server.connectThroughLocalhost` (Settings -> Extensions -> Remote - WSL -> Connect Through Localhost) from disabled to enabled, and that fixed the issue for me.

No idea why this happened in the first place though, it was working fine without enabling this setting for over 2 months, and then suddenly it stopped working.

Maybe the IP of the virtual machine changed in some unexpected way?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. I used @thnee's solution of changing the connection method. I found this easiest to do by using the `settings UI > Remote > Connection Method`

Answer (score 0):

I think that may cause by the conflict between `~/.ssh/config` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. I delete the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and try again, find that the vscode can connect to remote successly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> setting ->terminal>integrated>default profile was null, I made it as sh this is the fix for it:

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is reset the VS Code version. At least that fixed the problem for me after 6 hours of research and trying. I have set the current version to the previous month.

Answer (score -1):

I have this issue all of a sudden and after a few trials, I found install another distro using WSL-1 fixes the problem. You can safely unregister the new distro afterwards.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30589634)